# How to cancel match request before onRoomCreated event triggers? Google Play Services - Real Time Multiplayer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, multiplayer, prime31

How to properly cancel a realtime multiplayer match if the user cancels the match before onRoomCreated is triggered? At this time there's no room id to call leaveRoom.

GPGMultiplayer.startQuickMatch (1, 1);

Right after this the user presses cancel for some reason now how do I cleanup?